# Segmentation using *both* RGB and Depth Images

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have two frames here, one is an RGB image, and the second is a depth map of the same RGB image. The image is here:

[image]

I'd like to perform foreground extraction on the two plants directly in front using both images. If this isn't clear, it is the two whitish plants that the depth map was able to capture. Only those two. My end result ideally, is a color image of the two flower-plants in a black background- from the green tip to the bottom. I am thinking maybe masking would be useful?

My question, is if I can combine the color data found in the RGB images, with the "shape" data found in the depth map? The reason why I am so intrigued with combining the two, is because they both capture important information: One gives me color, while the other gives me shape.

If I only had the RGB image, then I would have difficulty isolating the two plants in front due to all the similarly colored plants in the back, and I potentially lose the very tip of the plant, which is green, but also a very important part of the plant.

On the contrary, if I only had the depth map, then I lose all the surface features of the plants, particularly color, which is important for identifying the health condition of the plant.

If anyone could provide any assistance with how I can "combine" RGB and depth, to extract the two plants, please let me know!

Comment: Can you post the two images separately (makes it easier to import and test stuff). *I am assuming that they are the same resolution and are approximately mapped?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the depth image to RGB image along channel axis. Presuming you are using CNN based model for segmentation, your input to the model will 4 channels, 3 from RGB image and 1 from depth image. The neural network will learn how to encode the depth information.